# How to write this Python for loop as a ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
stuart = 0
kevin = 0    
for itr, char in enumerate(word_list):
    if char in "aeiou":
        kevin += len(word_list) - itr
    else:
        stuart += len(word_list) - itr
```

Can I write the if/else statement as a ternary operator?

I tried the following to no avail:

```
(kevin if (char in "aeiou") else stuart) += len(word_list) - itr
```

and

```
kevin += len(word_list) - itr if char in "aeiou" else stuart += len(word_list) - itr
```

Is there a way to write this as a ternary operator for more compact code?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. The left side of an assignment can't be an expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 9):

Put your variables in a dictionary instead, and then you can vary the *key* you are assigning to:

```
names = {'stuart': 0, 'kevin': 0}
for itr, char in enumerate(word_list):
    names['kevin' if char in "aeiou" else 'stuart'] += len(word_list) - itr
```

You can't otherwise use a conditional expression to switch out variables.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to change the *variable* on left-hand side of assignment. However you can use the `globals()` trick to assign to a global variable, though this is frowned upon, thus never do this:

```
stuart = 0
kevin = 0    
globs = globals()
for itr, char in enumerate(word_list):
    globs['kevin' if char in 'aeiou' else 'stuart'] += len(word_list) - itr
```

For most perfomant code, one can gather the counts in a list of 2 items, and index them by `char in "aeiou"` which will choose index 1 (because `True == 1`!) for vowels and index 0 (as `False == 0`) for consonants; then unpack these to desired variables. Also, the length of `word_list` will be constant, but since Python cannot know this, the code will perform better if `len(word_list)` is placed outside the loop:

```
counts = [0, 0]
length = len(word_list)
for itr, char in enumerate(word_list):
    counts[char in "aeiou"] += length - itr

stuart, kevin = counts
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    kevin, stuart = ( kevin + len(word_list) - itr, stuart ) if char in "aeiou" else ( kevin, stuart + len(word_list) - itr )
```

Comment: I guess this answers the OP's question, but it's not exactly elegant. :)

Comment: Ewww, don't ever do that.